# Free up our old .onmicrosoft.com tenant name?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

Looking at migrating to O365 at the moment. A few years ago we made a test account stupidly using our companyname.onmicrosoft.com.

The account was later cancelled, deleted etc. but the name still shows up as in use.

Does anyone know how to contact O365 support without an account (every "support ticket" link takes me to a login page), surely there is a contact form for soon to be customers to use somewhere?

Anyone know whether they'd help us in getting that old name cleared for us to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Office 365 support there:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=threads&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&tm=1487908740489